# What Stack Exchange site (if any) would be appropriate for this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tried posting the following on Programmers.StackExchange.com, but it was closed as <strike>off topic</strike> not constructive.  Is there a Stack Exchange site for this question?

> Has anyone come across a "somewhat complete" list of the most common
>   textbox input patterns that programmers need to validate against? I
>   have come up with a short list on my own but would like to get
>   something more complete. What I have so far:
>
> ```
> * Social Security Number
> * Phone Number
> * Email Address
> * Web Address
> * Zip Code
> ```

Comment: You'll need to edit it in a way it's no longer a "fill out the rest of my phone directory" request

Comment: Minor clarification: [the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99599/common-input-patterns-that-need-to-be-validated) was closed a "not constructive".

Comment: I just can't get anything past you can I Anna?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the close reason because input validation approaches in general aren't off-topic on Programmers.

Comment: what is the *purpose* of this list? Why do you need to create such a list? What is your actual problem? Maybe you could explain THAT.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, here is the explanation from my original post:   
I am interested in building a SharePoint WebPart that would provide several methods for validating input (sorely lacking if you've ever used SharePoint). While I plan on providing a way for people to enter regex and use other methods for custom validation I would like to provide a complete/useful list of what I consider the most common patterns that require validation. These pre-determined patterns would have all validation logic already implemented.

Comment: And the follow up:  
Also, I'm not sure how familiar you are with SharePoint, but often the people defining what fields need to be present do not have the skills to implement proper validation using Regex or other methods. The fact that non-programmers are creating the structure causes the need for pre-defined lists of common patterns.

Comment: @abe maybe ask it on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com then?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, I considered it, but I really think that the people that would have experience with this type of task are web developers and not SharePoint admins/users/developers.  While my end goal is to use this for something in SharePoint the question itself really does not require any sort of SharePoint knowledge/expertise.  Seems like like it would be an odd fit for that site.

Comment: @abe "Let's make a list of X" is still not a great question. Lists are for shopping

Comment: @jeff, Ok sounds like there is no SE home.  Maybe I'll try my luck with Yahoo Answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

I actually thought it was a constructive question for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), if it would have been phrased in a more descriptive way.  Reading the comments helped tremendously, and feedback from there should have been rolled back into the question.

I actually do have a list of a few more items that I would have provided as an answer, but now that it's closed I cannot.

Comment: @Abe Miessler if you end up reposting the question somewhere, please update this meta question with a link to the reposted/rephrased question.

Comment: I posted it up in the LinkedIn "End to End Web Developers" group discussion board.  Not sure where else to post it.  You can see it here: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Common-input-patterns-that-need-2204708.S.65877362